# Broken Sandisk usb stick

Tags: usb

A friend of mine is afraid of losing lots of data from her lawyer work because of a broken usb stick (shown on picture below).

My idea is the following: As you can see at the bottom of the stick, there are 8 copper pins. I have thought that 4 of these pins were actually the same circuit point as principal ones. If so, I could make a "bridge" and try to read the card.

What do you think, am I right? do I have any chance?
Do you think that some IC is also broken and there is no option to access the data?

Thank for reading and sorry for my english ;)
[image]

Comment: Would this be an appropriate time for a reminder that keeping the only copy of any important data in a single location is just asking for trouble? If the data is valuable, then don't even touch it. Take it to a data-recovery specialist.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agreed. Don't do *anything* at all. Everything you do risks further damage.

Comment: I agree you both.

Comment: Sorry, I touched Intro too soon ;) She thought she had a backup, but she does not...

Comment: Just to calm my curiosity... Are any of those 8pins, a "back door" of 4 principals?  I will told her to carry it to a specialist. Thank for your time!

Comment: Melebius, what you say makes sense to me, thanks for the info and your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to provide same circuit points on the other side of a highly-integrated device. There can be even some electronics under the USB connector, so the part without connector may be not able to work alone.

These solder points are more likely designated for SMD LEDs (and resistors for them probably). My friend attached an SMD LED to a disassembled Kingston flash drive looking similar and it really works to indicate data transmission.

Comment: Melebius, what you say makes sense to me, thanks for the info and your time :)